# An estimate for $L$-harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $L $ be a linear second order uniformly elliptic operator defined in divergence form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u$ be an $L$-harmonic function. I recall reading somewhere an estimate of the following kind:
$$ \frac{1}{r}\int_{B_r} u^2 dx \leq C \int_{\partial B_r} u^2 d\sigma,$$
where $B_r \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a ball of radius $r$, and $C$ is a constant. I cannot recall where I found this estimate, and I also do not recall exactly what restrictions needed to be placed on the coefficients of $L$. I would really appreciate the help if anybody knows this estimate and can point to a reference. Thanks a lot!